# Get widget options in template

Tags: javascript, node.js, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

I know it's possible to add an alias to `index.js`, but this is [not recommended for NPM modules](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/commit/08bb6bc2d7d9ee22bbbb5bc97f86086c74852bac).

So, how do I pass JavaScript variables like the `options` object to a Nunjucks template?

`data.widget` only contains an `id`, the `type` and `editable`. Strangely enough, it doesn't contain the `label`.

index.js

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Privacy Cookie Widget',

  [...]
}
```

widget.html

```
<div class="[...]-widget">
  [...]

  {{ data.widget.label }} <!-- Nothing. -->

  [...]
</div>
```

home.html

```
[...]
{{ apos.singleton(data.[global|page], 'widgetName', 'widget-name', {}) }}
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a template you can get to your widgets root options config like this

```
{{ apos.log(apos.modules['my-cool-widgets'].options.coolStuff) }}
```

Where `coolStuff` is defined in `my-cool-widgets/index.js`

```
module.exports = {        
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',        
  label: 'Cool Widg',
  coolStuff: {
    array: [1,2,3,4],
    hello: 'boom boom',
    hehe: true
  },
  addFields: [...]        
};
```

Comment: Easy as always, thanks! And another thanks for the `apos.log` hint. :)